# Hibernate StaleObjectStateException, what's that as a Spring data access exception?

Tags: hibernate, spring

Which Spring exception maps onto org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException ?

We have a DAO that is annotated with

```
@Repository
```

We have an enitity that has a property annotated with

```
@Version
```

When the optimistic locking fails, a Spring exception is thrown, but I can't figure out which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be [`HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException.html), but testing it is as simple as calling a reporisoty method which only does

```
throw new StaleObjectStateException("foo", "bar");
```